# page isn't working after installing ioncube

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7, ioncube

I've downloaded a wordpress template and it needs to have Ioncube installed, I did as what digital ocean said on my vps and the right version for my php7.0 is installed (as I can see the result in phpinfo(); )but now when I go to my wordpress template page and it gives me the error

> This page isn’t working
>
> yourhost.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>   HTTP ERROR 500

this is my log

`[Thu Nov 09 06:25:02.686651 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9032] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 06:25:02.686691 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9032] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Thu Nov 09 06:25:50.830177 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9032] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
Failed loading /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so:  /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[Thu Nov 09 06:25:51.971658 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11316] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 06:25:51.971857 2017] [core:notice] [pid 11316] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 09 06:29:29.356068 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11316] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 06:29:30.508534 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31764] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 06:29:30.508625 2017] [core:notice] [pid 31764] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 09 06:53:32.691037 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31764] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 06:53:33.737673 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3759] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 06:53:33.737757 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3759] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 09 06:56:32.551814 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3759] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 06:56:32.752382 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14853] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 06:56:32.752490 2017] [core:notice] [pid 14853] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 09 07:01:24.790695 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 14853] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 07:01:25.989824 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18452] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 07:01:25.989955 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18452] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 09 07:01:31.080510 2017] [:error] [pid 18456] [client 5.232.32.241:24228] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:01:33.950712 2017] [:error] [pid 18455] [client 5.232.32.241:45501] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:01:36.156017 2017] [:error] [pid 18457] [client 5.232.32.241:35511] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:02:49.758464 2017] [:error] [pid 18479] [client 5.232.32.241:19653] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:09:30.678341 2017] [:error] [pid 18457] [client 5.232.32.241:46475] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:09:36.741121 2017] [:error] [pid 18459] [client 5.232.32.241:13475] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:09:59.726341 2017] [:error] [pid 18456] [client 5.232.32.241:18124] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:10:01.693749 2017] [:error] [pid 18480] [client 5.232.32.241:14882] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:10:09.060585 2017] [:error] [pid 18455] [client 5.232.32.241:16883] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:10:09.893809 2017] [:error] [pid 18458] [client 5.232.32.241:57989] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
[Thu Nov 09 07:14:15.677688 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18452] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 07:14:16.566425 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18910] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 07:14:16.566549 2017] [core:notice] [pid 18910] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 09 10:24:33.989899 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18910] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Nov 09 10:24:34.142330 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 317] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 09 10:24:34.142433 2017] [core:notice] [pid 317] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'`

please help me solve it

Comment: do you have any errors in logs?

Comment: Error 500 means something broke. Without more information we cannot say what it is that is broke. Try to source some info from your servers error logs and include it in the question.

Comment: can you provide site url?

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin how can I get the log ?! please tell me the code

Comment: @RajkumarGour http://supportpanel.net/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsupportpanel.net%2Fwordpress%2F30693_Avada-7%2Favada522%2Fwp-admin%2Fadmin.php%3Fpage%3Dduplicator-tools%26tab%3Dcleanup%26package%3Davadav522_193d32d5b789b4982571170822184418_archive.zip     this is the link

Comment: @Omid this really depends on your hosting/server. do you have access to command line?

Comment: /var/log/apache2/access.log erro.log,  please share these files

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin yes it's my VPS and I have sudo access to all

Comment: @RajkumarGour I put my log in post, please see it again

Comment: erro.log needed

Comment: @Omid seems that you shared your access.log, we need to see the error.log. If you are using nginx check like this: ls /var/log/nginx/*error*.log if you are using apache try this: ls /var/log/apache2/*error*.log

Comment: @RafailAkhmetshin oh I'm so sorry I am just a newbie, I changed it buddy

Comment: @RajkumarGour sorry, changed it Please take a look

Comment: /usr/lib/php/20151012/ioncube_loader_lin_7.0.so check this file is exists at this location or not

Comment: this log is missing the lines

Comment: [Thu Nov 09 07:10:09.893809 2017] [:error] [pid 18458] [client 5.232.32.241:57989] PHP Fatal error:  The file /var/www/html/wordpress/30693_Avada-7/avada522/wp-content/themes/$
(there is no file name here)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, although it says you need an ioncube_7, but I should install go with php5.6